# Unable to open particular URLs from inside Word

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

I'm getting the following error message when clicking some (not all) URLs in a Word doc:
"Unable to open [URL]. The Internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found. (HTTP/1.0 404)"

When I edit the hyperlink, everything looks fine.  If I copy the URL directly from the Address field in the Edit Hyperlink box and paste it into the browser, it works fine.  But it refuses to work from within Word.  There are other links in the document that do work.

FYI, there is no number sign (#) in the URL.

Any ideas?
Thanks.